# Random allocation of records between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to assign the values from Table B to Table A, but so that each record in Table B occurs in the same number of repetitions.

[image]

[Fiddle SQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=801ecb92f66ee75057a433f6d631f8ae)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions for this and mod arithmetic.  For simple repetition:

```
with a as (
      select a.*, rownum as seqnum
      from a
     ),
     b as (
      select b.*, rownum as seqnum, count(*) over () as cnt
      from b
     )
select a.col, b.col
from a join
     b
     on mod(a.seqnum - 1, b.cnt) = b.seqnum - 1;
```

For more random assignment, randomize the seqnums:

```
with a as (
      select a.*,
             row_number() over (order by dbms_random.random) as seqnum
      from a
      order by db
     ),
     b as (
      select b.*, count(*) over () as cnt,
             row_number() over (order by dbms_random.random) as seqnum
      from b
     )
select a.col, b.col
from a join
     b
     on mod(a.seqnum - 1, b.cnt) = b.seqnum - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ROWNUM for achieving the same:

```
SELECT
    COLOUR,
    EMP
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            COLOUR,
            ROWNUM RN
        FROM
            T1
    ) T1,
    (
        SELECT
            EMP,
            ROWNUM RN
        FROM
            T2
    ) T2
WHERE
    MOD(T1.RN, 2) + 1 = T2.RN
```

[Fiddler SQL QUERY](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c1a6f14746ac30bd56254fa1e627698c)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
with Employees as
 (select Emp, Row_Number() Over(order by 1) Rn
    from B
   cross join (select 1
                from Dual
              connect by level < (select count(1)
                                    from A) / (select count(1)
                                                          from B) + 1)
   order by Dbms_Random.Value),
Colours as
 (select Colour, Rownum Rn
    from A)
select t.Colour, k.Emp
  from Colours t
  join Employees k
    on t.Rn = k.Rn
```